# Salesforce namespacing issue with managed package

Tags: apex, visualforce, managed-package

We have a Vf page inside managed package which is using Salesforce merged fields in javascript, we are using this syntax: "{!JSENCODE(Proposal__c.Quote__c)}"

However, this expression some times resolves to namespaceprefix_Proposal__c.namespaceprefix_Quote__c(which is expected behavior) and some times it doesn't which led to error in the Managed package subscribers ORG.

We changed "{!JSENCODE(Proposal__c.Quote__c)}" to '{!JSENCODE(Proposal__c.Quote__c)}' and it worked fine for a while and then starts breaking.

Am I missing some thing here or is it some known issue?

Comment: If you add the specifics of when you do and do not see a problem that would help people comment. Your "changed" example in the question shows two identical Visualforce expressions. Generally, if the Visualforce page is part of the managed package the namespace is not needed.

Comment: Keith, the issue is highly intermittent, I have provided 'changed' example with two identical Vf expression but one wrapped in single Quote and other is wrapped in double Quote, changing double quotes to single quotes some time resolves issue for some time but then it starts failing again in some time. this expression is inside <script> tag, this woks absolutely fine is HTML or VF page tags thought. Also, this is only happening in the subscriber's ORG where we install our managed package, we have done packages earlier but never faced such issue...hope this explains the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add the namespace prefix to the object api name (namespaceprefix__Proposal__c) anyway - it will work anyway and will solve your problem.